# plot arrays by row with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two numpy arrays (a and b) with shape (16, 850) each. I'm displaying them row by row, e.g.

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(a[0], b[0])
plt.plot(a[1], b[1]) 
plt.plot(a[2], b[2])
...
plt.show()
```

Should I have to use a for loop to do it in a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a multi-dimensional array to `plot` and each column will be created as a separate plot object. We transpose both inputs so that it will plot each row separately.

```
a = np.random.rand(16, 850)
b = np.random.rand(16, 850)

plt.plot(a.T, b.T)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Suever. That worked because I needed to display 16 plots. That's why I said "row by row" :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
plt.figure()
for i in range(len(a)):
    plt.plot(a[i], b[i])
plt.show()
```

But the way that Suever shows is much Pythonic. However, not every function has something like that built-in.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to draw many lines is the use of a `LineCollection`. This might look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x = np.random.rand(N,3)
y = np.random.rand(N,3)

data = np.stack((x,y), axis=2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_collection(LineCollection(data))
```

for a bunch of lines consisting of 3 points each.

Find a comparisson for different methods and their efficiency in the answer to [Many plots in less time - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492963/many-plots-in-less-time-python/54544965#54544965).