# Many plots in less time - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have about 50 000 columns I want to plot in the same figure. Here is the code I use:

```
# "Xaxis" is a list containing the x-axis, and "data" a list of the 50 000 data series I want to plot.
for elt in data:
    plt.plot(Xaxis,elt)
```

This is a bit time consuming (I need to wait about 15min). Any suggestions to optimize the process/reduce the time ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One sentence answer: Use a `LineCollection`.

---

There are several options to draw many lines.

#### A. A loop

One can loop through the data and create one `plot` per line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


def loop(N, show=False):
    x = np.random.rand(N,3)
    y = np.random.rand(N,3)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(N):
        ax.plot(x[i], y[i])
        
    if show:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.close(fig)
```

#### B. Plot a matrix

Instead of calling `plot` several times, one can supply a matrix to `plot` where each column contains the values of a line. This will however still create as many `Line2D` objects as there are columns in the matrix.

```
def matrix(N, show=False):
    x = np.random.rand(N,3)
    y = np.random.rand(N,3)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.plot(x.T, y.T)
        
    if show:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.close(fig)
```

#### C. A `LineCollection`

A collection allows to create a single artist, which is rendered only once. This is the fastest option.

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
    
def linecoll(N, show=False):
    x = np.random.rand(N,3)
    y = np.random.rand(N,3)
    
    data = np.stack((x,y), axis=2)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.add_collection(LineCollection(data))
        
    if show:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.close(fig)
```

#### D. Single plot with nans.

A line will be intercepted at the positions of `nan` values in the data. This allows to plot a single `Line2D`, but with `nan`s at the end of each data block that makes up an individual line.

```
def fillednan(N, show=False):
    x = np.random.rand(N,3)
    y = np.random.rand(N,3)
    
    X = np.concatenate((x, np.ones_like(x)*np.nan)).flatten()
    Y = np.concatenate((y, np.ones_like(x)*np.nan)).flatten()
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.plot(X,Y)
        
    if show:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.close(fig)
```

#### Results.

Running those functions for different values of `N` through `%timeit` results in the following graph.

[image]

We see that the `LineCollection` takes the least amount of time. For large `N` the differences are significant. The loop is the least efficient, followed by the matrix. This is because both create `N` individual lines which need to be drawn. The single line with nans and the LineCollection are much more efficient, with the `LineCollection` still beating the `plot`.

Comment: "intercepted" did you mean "interrupted" ?