# How to draw different lines from given x,y values in a single list in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some y values in a string like 1124,2113,4563. Then I have extracted individual values from the strings like,

```
1124=> 1,1,2,4
2113=> 2,1,1,3
4563=> 4,5,6,3
```

These are all my y values and corresponding x values are 5 increments for each y like,

```
1124 =>(0,1),(5,1),(10,2),(15,4)
2113 =>(0,2),(5,1),(10,1),(15,3)
4563 =>(0,4),(5,5),(10,6),(15,3)
```

My target is to draw 3 different series of lines from the given values. I have 2000 strings and converted them to a list like following

```
list = [(0,1),(5,1),(10,2),(15,4),(0,2),(5,1),(10,1),(15,3),(0,4),(5,5),(10,6),(15,3)]
```

Now is it possible to draw the lines from this data or what do? expert advise needed. 
I have tried drawing with the following code

```
plt.scatter(*zip(*list))
plt.plot(*zip(*list))
```

this code continues to connect the last point to the next point thus I am not getting different lines. all lines are getting interconnected.
[Here is an image what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I3JF.png)

Comment: If you don't put everything in the same list, you will at least be able to plot several `plot`s, one for each series. If you have many of such series, using a `LineCollection` [is the most effective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544965/4124317) way of plotting.

Comment: Thank you for for your help, but I could not get linecollection to my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many of such series, using a `LineCollection` is [the most effective way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544965/4124317) of plotting many lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

strings = ["1124", "2113", "4563"]
y = np.array([list(map(int,list(s))) for s in strings])
x = np.tile(np.arange(y.shape[1])*5, y.shape[0]).reshape(y.shape)
segs = np.stack((x,y), axis=-1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x.flatten(), y.flatten())
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(segs))
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, to have the lines in different colors,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), 
           c=np.repeat(np.arange(len(segs)),segs.shape[1]), cmap="plasma")
lc = LineCollection(segs, cmap="plasma")
lc.set_array(np.arange(len(segs)))
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can you help me a little bit for drawing each line with different color and the output is much dense, need a more disperse out put.

Comment: Updated the answer concerning colors. As for the density of lines, I'm not sure what you mean. That is essentially given by the data, so you cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be you need to split the whole list into different sub-list.

```
k=0;
for i in range(0,len(list),4):
    name='sub_list_'+str(k)
    sub_list=list[i:i+4]
    plt.scatter(*zip(*sub_list))
    plt.plot(*zip(*sub_list),label=name)
    plt.legend()
    k+=1
```

Comment: it worked with different color but took a long long time. Thanks a lot for your help