# How to make multiple lines' color changing with values corresponding to gradient color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, line

I have thousands of lines, and each of them with a value between 0 and 1 related to a feature. What I want to do is to draw these lines and at the same time to show their feature by color. That is if a lines value is 0.5, then I want this line have the middle color of a colorbar. How can I build this code? The following is an example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
b_range=np.linspace(0, 1, 5)

for j in range(len(b_range)):
    b=b_range[j]
t=b+(1-b)*(1-x)/(1-0)   
ax.plot(x, t,color="red")


plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the documentation is quite clear https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html You can specify a tuple of RGB values

Comment: @ChatterOne I found it's very hard for me to understand. Can you explain me a little more. i hope i choose two color let's say "r" and "b", i want "r" corresponds to valure 1 and "b" to 0, how can i assign all other line's values with the middle color?

Comment: If you want to understand yourself, instead of having the solution ready-made try one step at a time, start with: `ax.plot(x, t, color=(b_range[j], 0, 0))`

Comment: @ChatterOne That's cool. And how about i want the color between '#377eb8','yellow','#e41a1c'? is there any methods i change the color=(b_range[j], 0, 0)) to make the corresponding color in the middle?

Comment: If you have more than ~10 lines, a `LineCollection` is [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492963/many-plots-in-less-time-python/54544965#54544965).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the colour maps in `cmap`:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

cdict = {'red':   ((0.0,  0.22, 0.0),
                   (0.5,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0,  0.89, 1.0)),

         'green': ((0.0,  0.49, 0.0),
                   (0.5,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0,  0.12, 1.0)),

         'blue':  ((0.0,  0.72, 0.0),
                   (0.5,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0,  0.11, 1.0))}

cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('custom', cdict)

for i in np.linspace(0, 1):
    # Plot 50 lines, from y = 0 to y = 1, taking a corresponding value from the cmap
    ax.plot([-1, 1], [i, i], c=cmap(i))
```

[image]

A full list of colour maps is available [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i need. In addition, can i personally change the 'plasma' color in cm.get_cmap? I would like to choose the color gradient in the list ['#377eb8','yellow','#e41a1c'] which is similar to blue to yellow to red. But how can i change it?

Comment: @IvyGao edited my answer, check it please.

Comment: Another small question. why i put the value 0 and 1, the color is the same. And how can i found the color dollows this ['#377eb8','yellow','#e41a1c'] changing? Thanks.

Comment: I found this one "cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['#377eb8','yellow','#e41a1c'])".. but the problem of the c=cmap(0.0) and c=cmap(1.0) still have the same color, which sould be from blue to red. What's the reason here?

Comment: `0` and `1` are different from `0.0` and `1.0`. You can use `0` to `255` or `0.0` to `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by yourself, with an Color variable control which color next

This is an example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def format_axes(ax):
    ax.margins(0.2)
    ax.set_axis_off()

points = np.ones(5)  # Draw 5 points for each line
text_style = dict(horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center',
                  fontsize=12, fontdict={'family': 'monospace'})
COLOR = (0, 0, 0.1)

def color_conv(color_range):
    return (COLOR[0] + color_range, COLOR[1], COLOR[2]) 

# Plot all line styles.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for color_ite in range(10):   
    ax.text(-0.1, color_ite, '-', **text_style)
    ax.plot(color_ite * points, color=color_conv(color_ite/10), linewidth=3)
    format_axes(ax)
    ax.set_title('line styles')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]